# How can I parse the response through Retrofit 2 if response can be both a JSon/HTML?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Hi I'm working with an API, which returns the login page when the session token is invalid/JSON response if the session is valid. How can I implement this with Retrofit, ie having multiple response types ?

P.S It's an old API and it can't be changed. I'm new to retrofit, I'll be really grateful of your help.

Comment: How login works in your app? what is source of credentials for login, is it user?  is there service which can be used to check to see if session token is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Would post this as comment as it's more a suggestion then actual answer but here it goes:

(If you're completely new to Retrofit leave a comment to explain it in more detail)

You could make your Call return a Response like so:

```
@GET("login/endpoint")
Call<Response> getLogin();
```

than you can make the call like this

```
Call<Response> getLogin = ApiService.getLogin();
getLogin.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
            //here you can access Response.body() and use it to determine wether it's json or html and react accordingly
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
            //todo: error message
        }
    });
```

note: the Response i've used is from the OkHttp Library.

If this doesn't work you could try to make your own converter which has a check for html/json and adding it in the creation of the retrofit instance. i'm not entirely sure how you can go about with that but this seems to have a general idea: [custom converter](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-replace-the-integrated-json-converter) from futurestudio.

If you need more guidance/clarification please let me know i'll be able to answer later today.